# Override the Tab control for a single Object

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I found this code to override it for an entire class:

```
{ Private declarations }
  procedure CMDialogKey(Var Msg: TWMKey) ;
  message CM_DIALOGKEY;

procedure TForm1.CMDialogKey(var Msg: TWMKey);
begin
  if (ActiveControl is TEdit) and (Msg.Charcode = VK_TAB) then
  begin
   //
  end else
    inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  ShowMessage('Tab is Pressed!');
end;
```

Which works fine (for the entire class).

Is there some easy to understand code (I'm a starting programmer) that i can use? Or can I change the code above to fit my needs?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do this.  I'm curious what you are trying to achieve with this code, however.  The `TAB` key makes me suspect that you are trying to control the sequence of controls that next receive focus when pressing `TAB`.  If that is the case, then I suggest you have a look at the `TabOrder` and `TabStop` properties of controls : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.TabOrder

Comment: I'm actually trying to make a tab shift in a PageControl and then SetFocus. The tab order doesnt extend to diffirent pages.

Comment: Are you using FMX or VCL?

Comment: To be clear, you would like the "final" control in a `TabSheet`, upon pressing `TAB` to select the next `TabSheet` and give focus to the first control it contains?

Comment: Axactly. Do you think I should change my question to that? I would like to have a deeper understanding into the workings of overriding the tab key. Hence the 'vague' question

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful if you could be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from comments, one way to do what you are asking is to make use of the `Tag` property that every VCL control has.  You could define a constant like :

```
const MOVE_NEXT = 123;
```

Then, in the designer, choose whichever control in the TabSheet is to be the final control that triggers a page change and set its `Tag` property to `123`.  Ideally, this is most likely to be the control with the highest `TabOrder` on the page.  You could also do this programmatically, of course.

[image]

In your method, then :

```
procedure TForm1.CMDialogKey(var Msg: TWMKey);
begin
  if (ActiveControl.Tag = MOVE_NEXT) and
     (Msg.Charcode = VK_TAB) and
     (PageControl1.ActivePageIndex < PageControl1.PageCount - 1) then
  begin
    PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := PageControl1.ActivePageIndex + 1;
    Msg.Result := 1;
    // note : it is good practice to set the message result to 1 
    // to indicate that you have handled the message.
  end else
    inherited;
end;
```

The method above will cause the `TAB` key to cycle through all of its pages, landing at each control in the `TabOrder` dictated by the contained controls.  The control with `Tag` property of `123` will trigger the selection of the next tab.  As it is written, it will cycle through the page control once and then leave to the next control on the form.

On the next cycle around, of course, the `PageControl` will remain on its final page and the `Tab` key will simply cycle through the controls on the final page before moving on.  You could have the page control reset to its first page each time, however, by doing something similar with the preceding `TabOrder` control on the form - for example :

```
procedure TForm1.CMDialogKey(var Msg: TWMKey);
begin
  if (ActiveControl.Tag = MOVE_NEXT) and
     (Msg.Charcode = VK_TAB) and
     (PageControl1.ActivePageIndex < PageControl1.PageCount - 1) then
  begin
    PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := PageControl1.ActivePageIndex + 1;
    Msg.Result := 1;
    Exit;
  end;

  // define new const MOVE_FIRST = 124 
  if (ActiveControl.Tag = MOVE_FIRST) and (Msg.Charcode = VK_TAB) then
  begin
    PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := 0;
    PageControl1.SetFocus;
    Msg.Result := 1;
    Exit;
  end;

  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: So as I understand this: ActiveControl.Tag is actually working parameter that will make an individual object override the tab key

Comment: @Eszee `ActiveControl` is a property of the form - it provides a reference to the control on the form that currently has focus.  If the currently focused control is `Edit1` then writing `ActiveControl.Tag` is the same as writing `Edit1.Tag`.

Comment: Thank you verry much J. I'm gonna leave the question as is, since you have given me a broad perspective with a single example. Perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

While @J... sugestion would work it is not intuitive as you would have to tab through every control on that specific page on PageControll. 
Try tabing through about 50 components and you will se what I mean. Don't have any form with so many components. Then open a webpage and use TAB key to move between different controlls that web page is made of.

So why not use specific key combination for quickly moving through pages for PageControll like CTRL+TAB which is comonly used in many programs that support multiple tabs (most web browsers) or even working on multiple documents (older versions of Microsoft Word, Curent versions of Microsoft Excel, etc.)

Infact isn't such feature already implemented in Page Controll already?

Comment: Yes, `CTRL+TAB` will cycle between pages on a `PageControl`.  This doesn't seem to give the behaviour that OP is looking for, however.